# How to create RoboVM iOS APP in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, robovm

I'am insatlled RoboVM module. introduced a license key.

How to create RoboVM iOS APP in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Gradle installed in your Android Studio.

Start libgdx setup GUI tool

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/libGDX/1.6.1/gdx-setup.jar
```

Make sure to select IOS project.
[image: Setup GUI]

Click generate

When it finishes, import libgdx project into your workspace (File->Import->Gradle)

Connect your device to your machine (if you don't want to use simulator)

Right click on the IOS project and select Run As IOS Device Application (or IPhone/IPad Simulator Application. Whichever suits you).